# What is the equivalent of keras NonNeg weight constraint?

Tags: keras, pytorch

Keras has an option to force the weights of the learned model to be positive:

```
tf.keras.constraints.NonNeg()
```

But I couldn't find the equivalent of this in pytorch, does anyone know how can I force my linear model's weights to be all positives?

Tried asking this on other forums but the answers were not helpful.

Let's say I have a very simple linear model as shown below, how should I change it?

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,input , n_classes):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__()

        self.classify = nn.Linear( input  , n_classes)

     def forward(self, h ):

        final = self.classify(h)
        return final
```

I want to do exactly what the NonNeg() does but in pytorch, don't want to change what its doing.

This is the implementation of NonNeg in keras:

```
class NonNeg(Constraint):
    """Constrains the weights to be non-negative.
    """

    def __call__(self, w):
        w *= K.cast(K.greater_equal(w, 0.), K.floatx())
        return w
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggested answer is wrong.  You cannot simply use torch.abs here because absolute function is a non-monotonic mapping.  Both negative and positive input values will give the same output value. The correct way to approach this problem is as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class PosLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_dim, out_dim):
        super(PosLinear, self).__init__()
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn((in_dim, out_dim)))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros((out_dim,)))
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.matmul(x, torch.exp(self.weight)) + self.bias
```

The idea is to find a monotonic mapping between `self.weight` and the coefficient used for the linear regression.

Comment: but isn't it better to not use abs and instead somehow convert the negative values to 0? because if we use abs then a weight that was a large negative will become a large positive, which is not what the NonNeg is doing, so how should i change the code to do this instead of abs?

Comment: Does keras NonNeg do this. If you want to replicate what NonNeg does, then understand what it does and transform the code I posted to do this.

Comment: I am currently facing a problem that requires the weights to be positive : I need to model a monotonic function, and the stable way I found is using monotonic activation functions alongside positive weights

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is through the exponential function:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class ExpLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
        self.weight= nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(out_features, in_features))
        self.bias= nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(out_features))

    def forward(self, input):
        return nn.functional.linear(input, self.weight.exp(), self.bias.exp())
```

This template could also be used with the absolute value function, which I think would be more pythonic than the accepted answer (from @Serge de Gosson de Varennes).

Answer (score 1):

The above-accepted answer from @Serge ensures a positive weight **but does not provide the intended result**. The question is how to impose constraints (in this case *non-negativity*) on the weights of a neural network.

One way is to modify the functional interface to redefine the forward:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class NonNegLinear(nn.Linear):
    def forward(self, input):
        return F.linear(input, self.weight.clamp(min=0.), self.bias.clamp(min=0.))

class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_dim, out_dim):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__()
        self.linear = NonNegLinear(in_dim, out_dim)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)
```

Below is a sample result:

```
model = Classifier(3, 1)
u = torch.rand(3)
print(model.linear.weight.data)
print(model.linear.bias.data)
print(u)
print(model(u))

> tensor([[-0.4572,  0.4727, -0.4344]]) 
> tensor([0.2947]) 
> tensor([0.5978, 0.8494, 0.3751]) 
> tensor([0.6962], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

Negative weights and bias are assigned a minimum value of 0 in the forward pass.

Another way is to manually modify weights after each optimization step, as explained [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/set-constraints-on-parameters-or-layers/23620)